# How to add items to existing list of objects?

Tags: c#, list

I have three classes:

```
public class M2ArticleMain
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public List<M2ArticleAttributeWeb> Attribut_Web { get; set; }
}

public class M2ArticleAttributeWeb
{
   public int Web_Id { get; set; }
   public M2ArticleTmpMainSkus Variants { get; set; }
}

public class M2ArticleTmpMainSkus
{
   public DateTime TimeAdded { get; set; }
   public List<string> Skus { get; set; }
}
```

And I have two Lists in my code like this:

```
List<M2ArticleMain> data = new List<M2ArticleMain>();
List<M2ArticleAttributeWeb> attb = new List<M2ArticleAttributeWeb>();
```

In some part of my code firstly I (from foreach loop) add data to **attb** list where I add only **only some data** (because I don't have all data at this point), like this:

```
...
attb.Add(new M2ArticleAttributeWeb
    {
       Web_id = item.Id, //(item is from foreach loop)
       Variants = null   //this is **importat**, I left null for later to add it
    });
```

Next, after I fill **attb**, I add all this to **data** list:

```
...
data.Add(new M2ArticleMain
   {
      Id = item.Id_Pk,  //this is also from foreach loop,
      Attribut_Web = attb  //now in this part I have only data for Web_id and not Variants
   }
```

Now my question is **How to Add items** later to **data** list to object *Variants*?

Something like this:

```
data.AddRange( "how to point to Variants" = some data);
```

Comment: Create a reference to the `M2ArticleAttributeWeb` instance?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay wouldn't crating a reference to M2ArticleAttributeWeb empty my existing list?

Comment: `Attribut_Web` is a `List` type how do you know which `Variants` will be fill in? could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: No, you can have multiple references to a single object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `M2ArticleAttributeWeb` type holding your `Variants` property is the member of a collection. That is, there are potentially many of them. You can reference an individual `Variants` property like this:

```
data[0].Attribut_Web[0].Variants
```

But you need to know which items you want to add map to which `data` and `Attribut_Web` indexes/objects in order to assign them properly. That probably means another loop, or even a nested loop. That is, you can see **all** of your `Variants` properties in a loop like this:

```
foreach(var main in data)
{
    foreach(var attrw in main)
    {
        var v = attrw.Variants;
        // do something with v
        Console.WriteLine(v);
        // **OR**
        attrw.Variants = // assign some object
    }
}
```

It's also much better practice to create your collection properties with the object, and then give them **private** set attributes:

```
public class M2ArticleMain
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public List<M2ArticleAttributeWeb> Attribut_Web { get; private set; } = new List<M2ArticleAttributeWeb>();
}

public class M2ArticleAttributeWeb
{
   public int Web_Id { get; set; }
   public M2ArticleTmpMainSkus Variants { get; set; } 
}

public class M2ArticleTmpMainSkus
{
   public DateTime TimeAdded { get; set; }
   public List<string> Skus { get; private set; } = new List<string>();
}
```

Now instead of assigning `Attribut_Web = attb`, you would need to `.Add()` to the existing List.

Comment: Great, thank you for help.